# Matching pair objects

Tags: javascript

This is regarding JavaScript. I have a response data like this which contains pairs of objects (note that the pairs can also be of 3 or 4 or any number and the pair ids are sorted). I want to alter the data such that after each matching pairs, I append one object.

```
[
  {
    pairId: 1,
    name: "abc",
    count: 10
  },
  {
    pairId: 1,
    name: "xyz
    count: 20
  },
  {
    pairId: 2,
    name: "abc"
    count: 15
  },
  {
    pairId: 2,
    name: "xyz,
    count: 25
  }
]
```

I want to achieve the data where I append one object after each matching pairs updating the count like this

```
[
  {
    pairId: 1,
    name: "abc",
    count: 10
  },
  {
    pairId: 1,
    name: "xyz
    count: 20
  },
  {
    pairId: 1,
    count: 30
  },
  {
    pairId: 2,
    name: "abc"
    count: 15
  },
  {
    pairId: 2,
    name: "xyz,
    count: 25
  }
  {
    pairId: 2,
    name: "mno,
    count: 5
  }
  {
    pairId: 2,
    count: 45
  }
]
```

Can anybody help achieve this?

While this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects) seems like a duplicate but I also wanted to know how to achieve pushing item to the end of last matching paired item.

Comment: are pair ids sorted

Comment: @cmgchess The pair ids are sorted

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Most efficient method to groupby on an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: While it may answer the question partially, I wanted to know how to push an item to the last known matching pair item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with a loop and try to juggle the current "run" of matching ids, and handle when you encounter a new id, and handle the start/end edge cases.

But a simpler solution is to group your elements by id, and for each group, if it has more than one element, add a new element with the sum of that group's `count` field.

```js
const items = [
  {
    pairId: 1,
    name: 'abc',
    count: 10,
  },
  {
    pairId: 1,
    name: 'xyz',
    count: 20,
  },
  {
    pairId: 2,
    name: 'abc',
    count: 15,
  },
  {
    pairId: 2,
    name: 'xyz',
    count: 25,
  },
  {
    pairId: 3,
    name: 'xyz',
    count: 25,
  },
];

// Group the items by pairId
const groups = items.reduce(
  (groups, item) => ({
    ...groups,
    [item.pairId]: [...(groups[item.pairId] || []), item],
  }),
  {}
);

// For each group, if has more than one element, append a new one with the sum
// of the previous elements. Object.values() takes advantage of the facts that
// object keys are iterated over in insertion order, so the resulting array is
// in the same order as the original one
const result = Object.values(groups).flatMap((group) => [
  ...group,
  ...(group.length > 1
    ? [
        {
          ...group[0],
          count: group.reduce((sum, item) => sum + item.count, 0),
        },
      ]
    : []),
]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a solution with manual loops and by keeping track of the previous id and the the sums. the current `pairId` not equal to `prevPairId` means a new group has started then we push the summed object to the array and reset the group sum `prevSum` and set the `prevPairId` to current `pairId` .
`count !== undefined` check to handle edge case happening at the end of the array where `data[i]` is `undefined`. (Note the loop is running for array length + 1 times)

```js
const data = [  {    pairId: 1,    name: "abc",    count: 10  },  {    pairId: 1,    name: "xyz",    count: 20  },  {    pairId: 2,    name: "abc",    count: 15  },  {pairId: 2,    name: "xyz",    count: 25  },    {    pairId: 2,    name: "xyz",    count: 5  }]


let prevPairId, prevSum = 0, newData = []
for (let i = 0; i <= data.length; i++) {
  const { pairId, name, count } = data[i] || {}
  if (pairId !== prevPairId) {
    if (prevPairId) newData.push({ pairId: prevPairId, count: prevSum })
    prevSum = 0
    prevPairId = pairId
  }
  if (count !== undefined) {
    newData.push({ pairId, name, count })
    prevSum += count
  }
}

console.log(newData)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It does work and also just a question if its better for a loop to run array length + 1?

Comment: yeah as long as you handle the undefined case in the last iteration

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr = [
  {
    pairId: 1,
    name: "abc",
    count: 10
  },
  {
    pairId: 1,
    name: "xyz",
    count: 20
  },
  {
    pairId: 2,
    name: "abc",
    count: 15
  },
  {
    pairId: 2,
    name: "xyz",
    count: 25
  }
];

function append(arr){
    let new_arr = [];
    let current_id = arr[0].pairId;
    let current_sum = 0;
    //iterate arr
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        //if next pair or the end
        if(current_id!=arr[i].pairId){
           //push new element
           new_arr.push({
            pairId : current_id,
            count  : current_sum,
           });
           //refresh sum and change current id
           current_id  = arr[i].pairId;
           current_sum = 0;
           i--;
        } else {
           new_arr.push(arr[i]);
           current_sum += arr[i].count;
        }
    }
    //push last
    new_arr.push({
            pairId : current_id,
            count  : current_sum,
           });
    return new_arr;
}
console.log(append(arr));
```

something like this: it is iterate through all cycle and if the id have changed then the pair also changed and the algorithm can calculate and paste new element, also in the end of cycle pushed last element.